# How to forbid barrow to all citizens and military?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to create barrow for trap corridor, and dont want to any dwarf go into it even to recharge traps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily use a burrow to specifically *forbid* travel through a certain area, but what you can do is create a burrow that encompasses your entire fort and then assign all of your dwarves to that burrow - by doing this none of your dwarves will leave unless they're starving or dying of thirst.

However, a much easier way to do this would be to simply [forbid](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Forbid) the traps in question - forbidden objects will not be handled by your dwarves in any way, so the traps won't be reloaded. You can forbid an entire group of objects using the <kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd> keys, which would let you forbid all of the traps in your trap corridor with one action.